# How do I make promise a map function with multiple dynamic variables in javascript/typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, promise, map-function

ok maybe what I was explaining before is hard to explain.

Actually I am using AWS Dynamodb to run some queries and I am trying to display them in a chart (NGX-Charts) in angular4 . Now for the data to need to be displayed in the chart they need to be like this example  **var shirtInfo =**

```
[
 {
"name": "Red Color",
"value": 10
 },
 {
"name": "Blue Color",
"value": 20
 },
 {
"name": "Green Color",
"value": 5
 },
]
```

You can see an example at this [link](https://swimlane.github.io/ngx-charts/#/ngx-charts/pie-chart) and if you click on DATA on the left side you can see the format the data is in the same way I have on the example above. Since I am using AWS Dynamodb there is no batchquery so I have to run each query each one by one. So instead of writing a query for each color someone did help me and we create a array with the colors in it and we used a function map for each color which is working here it is down here after we get Data back from Dynamodb I need to access the Object "data" property Count we get that using data.Count in there is the amount of data returned if the database had 10 Red shirts returned the value of data.Count = 10

```
getShirtcolorsCount(){
var params;
var colors;
var promises;
var docClient = new DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

colors = ['Red', 'Blue']; // <--- make code generic
promises = colors.map(function (color) {
    // Query voor Shirts 
    var param = {
        TableName: 'ShirtApp',
        IndexName: 'Shirt-index',
        KeyConditionExpression: 'ShirtC = :sbs '
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ':sbs': color // <-- make it dynamic to avoid code duplication

        }
    };
    return docClient.query(params).promise();
});

// Make sure to return the promise    
return Promise.all(promises).then(function (responses) {
    console.log('Success');  
    var shirtInfo = responses.map(function (data, i) {
        return {
            name: color[i] + 'Color',
            value: data.Count
        };
    });
    return shirtInfo;
}).catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});
}
```

since I want to display that value in a chart for each color you can see in the above code I had this piece of code that put the data in the right format for the chart. Check the piece of code down here.

```
var shirtInfo = responses.map(function (data, i) {
    return {
        name: color[i] + 'Color',
        value: data.Count
    };
});
```

That works fine but I am trying to use another chart which is this one [link](https://swimlane.github.io/ngx-charts/#/ngx-charts/bar-horizontal-stacked) To display that chart the data need to be in another format So let say in my Database which has 10 Red shirts  3 are Size Small , 2 are Size Medium and 5 are Size Large .So now Instead of having an array of colors [Red, Blue , Green] and run queries of each color I want to run  Query for color  "Red" 3 times one for Size Small , one for Size Medium and one for Size Large . The Same for the other Colors. I dont know How I should accomplish that? Do I need to make 2 arrays something like this

```
colors = ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow'];
sizes = [ 'Small', 'Medium' , 'Large'] ;
```

And with a map function inside a map function

```
    promises = colors.map(function (color)    {

    sizepromises = sizes.map)function (size)    {

             var param{....}
      }

    }
```

I know that the query  need to be like this it is almost the same as in example I just added 2 more fields

```
 var param = {
TableName: 'ShirtApp',
IndexName: 'Shirt-index',
KeyConditionExpression: 'ShirtC = :sbs ',
 FilterExpression: 'Size = :ftr',                
ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ':sbs': color,  // ---color is dynamic
    ':ftr':size'    //  ---size also need to be dynamic
}
```

And the var Shirtinfo needs to be like this to work in the new chart

```
 [
 {
 "name": "Red Color",
"series": [
  {
    "name": "Small",
    "value": 3
  },
  {
    "name": "Medium",
    "value": 2
  },
  {
    "name": "Large",
    "value": 5
  }
 ]
 },
 {
 "name": "Blue",
   "series": [
   {
    "name": "Small",
    "value": 2
   },
   {
    "name": "Medium",
    "value": 2
   },
   {
    "name": "Large",
    "value": 4
   }
  ]
 }
  ]
```

I changed and added a lot I something need more info add it in the comment I will check it out

Comment: would love to help, but have no idea what you're trying to do.

Comment: I'll update the question with more info

Comment: won't this work? I can' say without learning more about what responses is like


`shirtinfo = responses.map(function (data, i) {
        return {
            name: color[i] + 'Color',
            size: data.size,
            value: data.Count
        };
    });`

Comment: @BinodPant I need help with the map function too for the query if not it wont even work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this you'll probably want to break things up into reusable functions and reduce/transform the data directly following the query, rather than transforming everything at the end.

ShirtService.ts

```
class ShirtService {

    constructor(private docClient) {

    }

    queryShirt(color, size) {
        // Query voor Shirts
        const param = {
            TableName: 'ShirtApp',
            IndexName: 'Shirt-index',
            KeyConditionExpression: 'ShirtC = :sbs ',
            FilterExpression: 'Size = :ftr',
            ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                ':sbs': color,  // ---color is dynamic
                ':ftr': size    //  ---size also need to be dynamic
            }
        };
        return this.docClient.query(param).promise().then((response) => {
            return {
                name: size,
                value: response.Count
            };
        });
    }

    getShirtColorCount(color) {
        const sizes = ['Small', 'Medium', 'Large'];
        const promises = sizes.map((size) => {
            return this.queryShirt(color, size);
        });
        return Promise.all(promises).then((series) => {
            return {
                name: color + ' Color',
                series: series
            }
        });
    }

    getShirtColorsCount() {
        const colors = ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow'];
        const promises = colors.map((color) => {
            return this.getShirtColorCount(color);
        });
        return Promise.all(promises);
    }
}
```

ExampleComponent.ts

```
class ExampleComponent {

    constructor(private ShirtService) {

    }

    doSomething() {
        this.ShirtService.getShirtColorsCount().then((data) => {
            // Do something with data.
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.error(err);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a return var ?The code should be in a service and I need to call it from a component

Comment: I assume you're referring to angular?

Comment: Yes my bad I mean angular I will try the updated code now

Comment: I just used it and it looks like its working :) thanks alot